# mysql - alternative for repeated subquery in a long query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Am inserting a row of one table to another, for this I have a query like

```
INSERT INTO table1 
        (id,name,fieldname,address) 
SELECT (SELECT id FROM usertable WHERE name = 'namevalue'),
        name,
       ( SELECT fieldname FROM fielddata WHERE id IN 
         (SELECT id FROM usertable  WHERE name = 'namevalue') ),
       address 
FROM   sourcetable 
WHERE  cond = 'value'
```

here in the above query the following subquery is repeated twice, is there a way to use the subquery only once and retain the value and use it elsewhere.

```
SELECT id FROM usertable WHERE name = 'namevalue'
```

let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
    (id,name,fieldname,address) 
SELECT sub.id, 
   sub.name,
   ( SELECT fieldname FROM fielddata WHERE id IN sub.id ),
   sub.address
FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT id FROM usertable WHERE name = 'namevalue') id,
        name,
        address 
    FROM sourcetable 
    WHERE cond = 'value' 
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, fieldname, address)
SELECT usertable.id,
       sourcetable.name,
       fielddata.fieldname,
       sourcetable.address
FROM   sourcetable
  JOIN usertable ON sourcetable.cond = 'value'
                AND usertable.name = 'namevalue'
  LEFT JOIN fielddata ON fielddata.id = usertable.id
```